# ¿Como puedo crear un comando por consola al estilo django-admin startproject?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, flask

Estoy creando una librería que configure un proyecto de React.js + Ionic + Django con todas las configuraciones pertinentes para integrarlos, ya tengo el script. El cual le puse por nombre "django-ionic.py" al ejecutar el script de la forma tradicional con `python django-ionic.py` crea todo el proyecto sin problemas. Pero lo que yo quiero es poder anexar esto a un comando personalizado por consola tal cual como lo tiene django, me refiero al comando `django-admin startproject` para comenzar un proyecto nuevo de django, entonces mi duda es esta ya que no sé como crear dicho comando.

Me gustaría escribir en consola por ejemplo `django-ionic startproject "myApp"` y se ejecute dicho script para crear el proyecto, un saludo y gracias por tomarte el tiempo de leer mi pregunta.